# WordPress: overview post page to a particular post page

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm making a custom WordPress theme where I want two types of pages.

- An index page with excerpts of all the recent posts. This works. (overview post page)
- When you click on a post a page that shows the full content of the post.(post page)

Right now the index page works fine and shows all the recent posts. But when I click on a post I go to the index page template with that single post. Instead, I want to go to a different page template that shows the full post.

I have been trying out many things and searching for solutions but without luck. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Just create a `single.php` for showing  a single post .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a single.php  in your template folder for showing a single post .

Comment: This works. I have been searching for the past two days for an answer and you solved my problem within 2 minutes. Thank you.